# how to fill a empty field in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have a "reference code" field in my registeration form currently i am using below code to pre-populate this field via link. a default code is in my admin panel aslo. i want  that if user register without referral link that field should be automatically populated with $basic->reference_id

```
<input type="text" name="reference" value="{{ app('request')->input('ref')}}" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Reference ID *" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\BasicSetting;
use App\GeneralSetting;
use App\Mail\verifyEmail;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $basic = BasicSetting::first();
        if ($basic->reCaptcha_status == 1){
            Config::set('captcha.secret', $basic->secret_key);
            Config::set('captcha.sitekey', $basic->site_key);
        }
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'captcha',
            'country' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $basic = BasicSetting::first();
        $status = $basic->verify_status == 1 ? '0' : '1';
        $image25 = 'user-default.png';
        if ($basic->reference_id == $data['reference']){
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'phone' => $data['phone'],
                'address' => $data['address'],
                'country' => $data['country'],
                'zip' => $data['zip'],
                'under_reference' => $data['reference'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'verifyToken' => Str::random(40),
                'reference' => Str::random(12),
                'status' => $status,
                'image' => $image25
            ]);
        }else{
            $us = User::whereReference($data['reference'])->count();
            if ($us != 0)
            {
                $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'country' => $data['country'],
                    'zip' => $data['zip'],
                    'phone' => $data['phone'],
                    'address' => $data['address'],
                    'under_reference' => $data['reference'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                    'verifyToken' => Str::random(40),
                    'reference' => Str::random(12),
                    'status' => $status,
                    'image' => $image25
                ]);
            }else{
                Session::flash('type','danger');
                Session::flash('message','Opps.. Your Reference ID in not Correct.');
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }

        if ($basic->verify_status == 1){
            $thisUser = User::findOrFail($user->id);
            $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
        }
        return $user;
    }
    public function sendEmail($thisUser)
    {
        $general = GeneralSetting::first();

        $hh  = ['s_title'=>$general->title,'s_footer'=>$general->footer_bottom_text];

        $mail_val = [
              'email' => $thisUser['email'],
                'name' => $thisUser['name'],
                'g_email' => $general->email,
                'g_title' => $general->title,
                'subject' => 'Verify Account',
            ];
            Config::set('mail.driver','mail');
            Config::set('mail.from',$general->email);
            Config::set('mail.name',$general->title);
            Mail::send('auth.verify-email', ['email' =>$thisUser['email'] ,'verifyToken'=>$thisUser['verifyToken'],'site_title'=>$hh['s_title'],'site_footer'=>$hh['s_footer']], function ($m) use ($mail_val) {
                $m->from($mail_val['g_email'], $mail_val['g_title']);
                $m->to($mail_val['email'], $mail_val['name'])->subject($mail_val['subject']);
            });

    }
    public function verifyDone($email,$verifyToken)
    {
        $user = User::where(['email'=>$email,'verifyToken'=>$verifyToken])->first();
        if ($user)
        {
            User::where(['email'=>$email,'verifyToken'=>$verifyToken])->update(['status'=>1,'verifyToken'=>null]);
            Session::flash('type','success');
            Session::flash('message','Your Account Verified Successfully. Please Log In Now.');
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }else{
            Session::flash('type','danger');
            Session::flash('message','Opps..! Something is Wrong.');
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is $basic-reference_id coming from? What is it?

Comment: it is in database can be change from admin panel

Comment: `value="{{ request()->ref ?: $basic-reference_id }}"`

Answer (score 0):

In the controller where this form is submitted, check if the request has a valid value for the referral ID field. If it's valid you can use that, if it's invalid or empty you can use the basic referral ID.

I would set a variable in your controller at the start. Here is a suggestion that would use the request, but default to the basic reference if the request value was null:

`$referance_id = $data['reference'] ?: $basic->reference_id;

Here is an updated version of your controller that I think should work.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $basic = BasicSetting::first();
    $status = $basic->verify_status == 1 ? '0' : '1';
    $image25 = 'user-default.png';

    $reference = $data['reference'] ?: $basic->reference_id;

    $us = User::whereReference($data['reference'])->count();

    if ($us > 0) {
        Session::flash('type','danger');
        Session::flash('message','Opps.. Your Reference ID in not Correct.');
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'country' => $data['country'],
        'zip' => $data['zip'],
        'under_reference' => $data['reference'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'verifyToken' => Str::random(40),
        'reference' => Str::random(12),
        'status' => $status,
        'image' => $image25
    ]);

    if ($basic->verify_status == 1){
        $thisUser = User::findOrFail($user->id);
        $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: i need basic->reference only when field is empty

Comment: That's what my code does. Can you post your whole controller function that receives the form?

Comment: That's not your controller, that's your view. What does your function look like that receives the form submission?

Comment: sorry check now

Comment: check now please

Comment: I updated my answer. I refactored your controller so that it's much more simple and should work just like before, but now setting the reference id to the basic one if there is none in the $data array.